# adding your own SQLite database to an android application

Tags: android

how can we add our own SQLite database to an android project??

Comment: I normally don't say RTFM, but RTFM: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: This example will will interest you [http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Comment: This will help you to create ,insert ,delete or midify the SQLite Database. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I think he's compiling a list of `how to...` questions.  It could have been worse; many people come here asking for you to write code for them, like this site is some sort of free community based app creation tool.

Comment: Go through with this tutroial the best one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     private Context mycontext;

     //private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
     private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).sqlite"; //the extension may be .sqlite or .db
     public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
     /*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                             + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                             + "/databases/";*/

     public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
         super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
         this.mycontext = context;
         boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
         if (dbexist) {
             //System.out.println("Database exists");
             opendatabase();
         } else {
             System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
             createdatabase();
         }

     }

     public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
         boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
         if (dbexist) {
             //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
         } else {
             this.getReadableDatabase();
             try {
                 copydatabase();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 throw new Error("Error copying database");
             }
         }
     }
     private boolean checkdatabase() {
         //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
         boolean checkdb = false;
         try {
             String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
             File dbfile = new File(myPath);
             //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
             checkdb = dbfile.exists();
         } catch (SQLiteException e) {
             System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
         }

         return checkdb;
     }
     private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

         //Open your local db as the input stream
         InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

         // Path to the just created empty db
         String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

         //Open the empty db as the output stream
         OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(packagename)/databases/(datbasename).sqlite");

         // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int length;
         while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
             myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }

         //Close the streams
         myoutput.flush();
         myoutput.close();
         myinput.close();

     }

     public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
         //Open the database
         String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
         myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

     }



     public synchronized void close() {
         if (myDataBase != null) {
             myDataBase.close();
         }
         super.close();
     }
```

Comment: yes Obviously, the code is working on all devices.
moreover, I have also used in my application and it just works fine :)

Comment: @JaydeepKhamar : What is the DB_PATH??

Comment: Jaydeep Khamar , can you tell me full example as you done above?