# Where my application's database is stored

Tags: android, database

I`m new to Android developement.  I want to know by adding this code where the database physically exists in my application folder.

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = info.this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
     + TableName
     + " (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 INT(3));");
 Toast.makeText(this,"Database Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   /* Insert data to a Table*/
   myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
     + TableName
     + " (Field1, Field2)"
     + " VALUES ('Raj Gaurav', 24);");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String path = myDB.getPath()
```

[SQLiteDatabase.getPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getPath%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

The Default location of the SQLLiteDatabase is

```
   /data/data/ur packeage/databases
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access you data base you can use path as:

```
private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                        + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/";
```

refer this link for more info

[adding your own SQLite database to an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086962/adding-your-own-sqlite-database-to-an-android-application/5948819#5948819)

Comment: `File file = mycontext.getDatabasePath("DatabaseName");` it's possible that file does not exist. it is posible that parent directories of file doesn't exist, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your database in the folowing path
open file explorer
go to

```
data/data/yourprojectpath/databases
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: what if in some version or implementation of android it will change ?