# How datas retrieved from SQlite are stored as 'list of favorites' in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, favorites

I am developing an Android application where you should be able to browse certain recipes.

I am retrieving the information about the recipes from **SQLite** database table, and retrieved some columns in a **listview** form. Now I want to store some of the retrieved datas into my favourites page, when I click **favourite** button in list. How can it possible..I want to implement "Add to favourites" feature in my app

How can I store that kind of info in the form of **listview** Using **SQlite** database?

Any ideas? Example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a new table to your SQLite database called `favourites`, and store the recipe_id in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new Sqlite file using SQlite manager and then use these links to copy that database in your application.First put the database (SQlite file)in assets folder and then copy it using method shown in these answers:

[Database not copying from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945196/database-not-copying-from-assets/5945326#5945326)

[adding your own SQLite database to an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086962/adding-your-own-sqlite-database-to-an-android-application/5948819#5948819)

Comment: ThankYou, I already have such a database table and retrieved some columns in a listview form. Now I want to store some of the retrieved datas into my favourites page, when I click favourite button. How can it possible..I want to implement "Add to favourites" feature in my app. Please help me with any ideas or example codes.